# Open several tabs in one Internet Explorer window

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, batch-file

I am trying to create a batch script that opens up 2 websites in iexplorer (I need to use IE).

Problem is, the urls are opened in separate IE windows.
Is it possible to just have 2 tabs in 1 window?

```
taskkill /im iexplore.exe /f
taskkill /t /f /im chrome.exe
taskkill /t /f /im communicator.exe
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 4
start iexplore.exe http://site1
start iexplore.exe http://site2
start communicator.exe
```

Comment: PowerShell: http://superuser.com/questions/601850/open-a-url-file-in-a-new-tab-of-existing-ie-window-from-command-line/

Comment: @beatcracker, already mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use VBScript code to start a new [InternetExplorer.Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms970456.aspx) and open the tabs using  `navigate2` method with [navOpenInNewTab = 2048](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565688(v=vs.85).aspx) flag:

```
@echo off
findstr /r /c:"^::[^ ]" "%~dpnx0" > "%temp%\openIEtab.vbs"
cscript //b //nologo "%temp%\openIEtab.vbs"
del "%temp%\openIEtab.vbs"

::set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
::IE.visible = true
::IE.navigate2 "google.com"
::IE.navigate2 "bing.com", 2048
```

There are also powershell solutions ([example](https://superuser.com/a/877249/409372)).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a timeout right after the first website you're trying to open, like this. Timeout will wait whatever amount of seconds you set after the `/T` which might be what you're trying to accomplish with the `ping` command, unless you need to ping a specific address everytime.

```
taskkill /im iexplore.exe /f
taskkill /t /f /im chrome.exe
taskkill /t /f /im communicator.exe
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 4
start iexplore.exe http://site1
TIMEOUT>NUL /T 3 /NOBREAK
start iexplore.exe http://site2
start communicator.exe
```

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem because IE opens urls from command line always in new windows. That's why vbscript/powershell are required.